# has-any-authorithy directive in jhipster application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jhipster

I have created a new role ROLE_SUPERUSER in my jhipster application. I want a specific navbar menu to be visible to only admin and my new user.
I tried using has-any-authorithy as given in authority.directive.js but its not working.

I am using it in HTML like

has-any-authorithy="['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERUSER']"

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code says:

```
authorities = attrs.hasAnyAuthority.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',');
```

So it seems that the directive expects one string and not an array.

Try this:

```
has-any-authority="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPERUSER"
```

Comment: Tried has-any-authorithy="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPERUSER" also but it's not working.

Comment: I just realized that there is a typo in spelling of authority in your suggestion.That's why it was not working. After correcting it to has-any-authority="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPERUSER" it is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way to do this. You can create a service only for this directive and return a "joined" array like this :

code in your service :

```
this.feature_1 = {
    access: [ROLES.ROLE_ADMIN, ROLES.ROLE_SUPERUSER].join()
};
```

`ROLES` is a constant and an array of app roles defined in `app.constants.js`.

And in your template :

```
has-any-roles="{{accessService.feature_1.access}}"
```

By doing this, if you want to change the access rights, you have only to modify the `accessService`

Answer (score 5):

And now in 2017 it is:

```
 <a *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In .html you can use this:

```
has-any-role="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"
```

Comment: has-any-role directive is no more there in latest version of jhipster.

Answer (score 1):

In 2016 version it should be:

```
has-any-authority="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add on that there should not space between the comma separated authorities, It did not work for me with a space after ",". As it considers space also part of authority string :

```
> has-any-authority="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER"
> has-any-authority="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"
```

1st one will not work but second one will.

Answer (score 0):

Now by the end of 2020, I stuck with the same problem to restrict field with multiple authorities!

```
 <div *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERUSER']"> And this worked for me! </div>
```