# JHipster Authority Operations doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am using JHipster to develop my project with Angular1.
I want to hide some buttons etc. for security.

> '*jhiHasAnyAuthority'

command works for Angular2+ project but i am using Angular1 and i don't know how to hide elements according to authority.
Also i saw in navbar.html

> has-authority="ROLE_ADMIN"

are used by default to hide admin menu. When i try to use same command for my entity, nothing changes.

Comment: I think some compilling issues cause that error. I recompilied and it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question as yours which was nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022291/1009448)

I myself have used both `has-authority=""` and `has-any-authority=""` and as an example of your query on the navbar.html, let's assume you have created an entity named Manager, this will be only visible after login from a ROLE_MANAGER or ROLE_ADMIN.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" has-any-authority="ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_ADMIN">
    <a ui-sref="manage" ng-click="vm.collapseNavbar()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>
    <span class="hidden-sm" data-translate="global.menu.entities.manager">Manager</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Note: ROLE_MANAGER is a customer role added by me and not by the default jhipster generator.